# On (gcd) and (greatest-common-divisor) and other similar tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Despite the fact that the [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) tag has already been discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/on-the-gcd-tag) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19387#19387), it seems that the discussion about this probably deserves a separate thread.

At the moment there is [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd), which was made [synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisibility/synonyms) of [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility). (As a result of [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/on-the-gcd-tag).)

Later two new tags [least-common-multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-common-multiple) and [greatest-common-divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) were created. Already the creation of the new tags, despite the fact that [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) already existed, may suggest that some users were not satisfied with the fact that [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) was made a synonym of [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility). At least some users voiced this opinion [in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19387#comment71828_19387). Both these tags are [suggested synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisibility/synonyms) for divisibility. I recall seeing some downvotes there. (IIRC when I first saw that page, the total score was -1, meaning that there was at least one downvote.)

I think that the tags [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd), [least-common-multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-common-multiple) and [greatest-common-divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) should be dealt with in the same way. Having several tags for the same thing seems rather messy. The problem with these tags was also pointed out recently [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=21817366#21817366).

So it seems that we have two possibilities:

- Make [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) again a tag separate from [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility), i.e., cancel the synonym. (I am not sure, what happens with the questions currently tagged as [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) in this case.)
- Make the other two tags synonyms of [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility), too.

> What do you think? Should [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) be kept separate from [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility)? Or would it be better to make all g.c.d.-related tags synonyms?

---

I suggest that until some kind of consensus is reached, we should use both [greatest-common-divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) and [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) questions about g.c.d. This will make things easier if we later want to separate the tags - less posts will be needing retagging.

Comment: Do we also need to add (highest-common-factor) and (hcf)?  In the off chance that someone from England may happen into our group...

Answer (score 10):

I propose a tag [gcd-and-lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd-and-lcm) to be created into which gcd, lcm, greatest-
common-divisor etc. are mapped.

On the one hand, the notion of GCD (and related) is relevant and wide-spread enough to merit a tag beyond the very general [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility). On the other hand, the notions GCD and LCM are very closely related, and it makes sense to have a shared tag.

Comment: Is the word "and" in [tag:gcd-and-lcm] strictly necessary? I just realized there's some inconsistency regarding that in tag naming, because eg [tag:supremum-and-infimum] has "and" in it, but [tag:homology-cohomology] doesn't.

Comment: I certainly do not insist on the "and." It might be easier to parse with the end, and mainly I thought it was the local standard. There is also sequences-and-series. The one time I created such a tag, on MO, I did not use an "and" but called it "divisors-multiples" but regretted it when somebody did not get the intent that this is about "divisors and multiples" but rather thought it is an obscure modification of "divisors"

Answer (score 4):

Some partial steps today, at least partially related.

1. [highest-common-factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highest-common-factor) was made a synonym of the [greatest-common-divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) tag.
2. The [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) ⇒ [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) synonym has been removed. Unfortunately, when I created this synonym *(Why did I do that? I was young and dumb then, I guess. Now, I'm older.)* I also *merged* the tags, so this completely removed the [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) tag from the system. (Even those questions tagged only [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) when the mergonym was done are currently tagged only [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility).)
3. Suggested synonyms [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm) ⇒ [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) and [least-common-multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-common-multiple) ⇒ [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) have been unceremoniously quashed.
4. For good measure a [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) ⇒ [greatest-common-divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) has been introduced.

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely a step in the right direction.